# how can i update the variable value using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to store php array count value in the jquery variable. Actually i'm sending ajax request and on success i'm refreshing the specific class `.reloadCOnt`. In this class i'm executing foreach loop.

```
$productIds = array();
foreach($cookiProductsArray as $cProduct){
    $productIds[] = $cProduct['product_id'];
}
$selectedItem = count($productIds);
```

I tried two techniques:

**First**

```
<input type="hidden" id="sItemCount" value="<?php echo $selectedItem; ?>" />
var selectedItem = $('#sItemCount').val();
```

**Second**

```
var selectedItem = <?php echo $selectedItem; ?>;
```

But both are not giving updated value when i `alert(selectedItem)`, its updating after page refreshing but i need on ajax request. However I checked through php `echo $selectedItem` its updating properly after each ajax request. Can any guide me how can i update the `php array` value in `JS Var`. Thanks

Comment: Could you please also post your ajax request + success method ?

Comment: Also no need to count when jQuery can do it for you `$(".someClass").length`

Comment: @mplungjan Very Good Idea. So i can count the `.reloadCOnt ul li` using jquery `selector` and `length` function instead of update the value. but it will give me update length?

Comment: what is "update length" - and yes, I of course meant `$("some selector").length`

Comment: @mplungjan you give me good and short coded idea. Its working perfect I appreciate you and your knowledge.